# Measuring short time intervals in C on Ubuntu / VMware

Tags: c, time, measurement

I am trying to measure short time intervals, in order few of milliseconds. This proves to be some nontrivial task, since the ubiquitous `time()` function works on whole seconds precision. After some research I came out with the four methods seen in the code sample below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t t0, t1;
    double dt0;

    struct timespec t2, t3;
    double dt1;

    struct timespec t4, t5;
    double dt2;

    struct timeval t6, t7;
    double dt3;

    volatile long long i;

    t2.tv_sec = 0;
    t2.tv_nsec = 0;
    clock_settime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);
    clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME,  &t2);

    t0 = clock();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,  &t2);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t4);
    gettimeofday(&t6, NULL);

    getchar();
    for (i=0; i<1e9; i++) {};

    gettimeofday(&t7, NULL);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t5);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,  &t3);
    t1 = clock();

    dt0 = (double) (t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    dt1 = (double) (t3.tv_nsec - t2.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
    dt2 = (double) (t5.tv_nsec - t4.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
    dt3 = (double) (t7.tv_usec - t6.tv_usec) / 1e6;

    printf("1. clock():          [0]=%10.0f, [1]=%10.0f, [1-0]=%10.6f sec\n", (double) t0, (double) t1, dt0);
    printf("2. clock_gettime(R): [2]=%10ld, [3]=%10ld, [3-2]=%10f sec\n", (long) t2.tv_nsec, (long) t3.tv_nsec, dt1);
    printf("3. clock_gettime(M): [2]=%10ld, [3]=%10ld, [3-2]=%10f sec\n", (long) t4.tv_nsec, (long) t5.tv_nsec, dt2);
    printf("4. gettimeofday():   [4]=%10ld, [5]=%10ld, [5-4]=%10f sec\n", (long) t6.tv_usec, (long) t7.tv_usec, dt3);

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I compiled and run it with:

```
gcc -lrt -o timer.e timer.c; time ./timer.e
```

I used the `getchar()` call to introduce a couple of seconds delay to see a difference between `real` and `user` time reports, and the result was:

```
1. clock():          [0]=         0, [1]=   3280000, [1-0]=  3.280000 sec
2. clock_gettime(R): [2]= 823922476, [3]= 478650549, [3-2]= -0.345272 sec
3. clock_gettime(M): [2]= 671137949, [3]= 325864897, [3-2]= -0.345273 sec
4. gettimeofday():   [4]=    823924, [5]=    478648, [5-4]= -0.345276 sec

real    0m6.659s
user    0m3.280s
sys     0m0.010s
```

As you can see, the only meaningful result is the correlation between method 1 and the `user` time reported by the `time` command.

This brings a couple of questions:
1. Why are results 2-4 meaningless?
2. How do I measure the real time spent running a program, like the `real` number `time` reports?

My environment is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit on VMware on Windows 7 on an AMD based HP laptop.

Comment: If this is for testing purposes, you might find it helpful to increase the number of iterations. This of course will make the test run longer, but can make use of lower resolution timing measurements.

Comment: @MichaelMior - it is used for very rough benchmarking - I am trying to compare run time of some algorithm that is executed on the host (linux) and on a hardware accelerator that is connected via USB. In both cases, the caller is the same program, the host program, and I need a way to get the total time it just "sits and waits" for the external hardware to finish its work. This is why clock() is not the answer, b/c it doesn't count for the waiting time (as demonstrated here by the getchar() call).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're on the right track with `clock_gettime()`.

However, you ought to get rid of  those `clock_settime()` calls: simply call `clock_gettime()` before and after a block of code, and look at the difference.

Also, when computing the difference, you should take both `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` into account; your current code just looks at the nanosecond component and ignores the full seconds.

On my Ubuntu system the following code gives a pretty accurate measurement of the time it takes to execute the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec t2, t3;
    double dt1;

    volatile long long i;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,  &t2);
    for (i=0; i<1e9; i++) {};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,  &t3);
    //time in seconds
    dt1 = (t3.tv_sec - t2.tv_sec) + (double) (t3.tv_nsec - t2.tv_nsec) * 1e-9;
    printf("%f\n", dt1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This correction does what I am looking for. Every once in a while one just misses to see the obvious. I thought that the _sec and _nsec fields sore the same data in different precision, but now I see that it is the whole and nanosec parts of the time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Some hint about measuring time down to micro and even nano seconds http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: Thanks for pointing to an explanation on rdtsc. May be useful in some contexts, but I am trying to figure out why the code I wrote does not give the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `clock_settime` calls do not what you think they do. If you'd have the permission they would simply set the system wide clock to `0`, probably not what you want. Almost all POSIX functions have a return value that tells you if the call succeeded. Usually it is a bad idea to ignore that value. For your case in particular I think that it should have given this value as it can be found in the `man` page:

> EPERM  clock_settime() does not have permission to set the clock
>   indicated.

Luckily you don't have the permissions to set the clock as simply as this :)

Comment: I added the settime after receiving the strange results from gettime. Apparently, it did not have any effect on the result.

Comment: @ysap, this is exactly what I am saying. It has no effect on the result since **it fails**. Otherwise it would have dramatic consequences for your machine, setting your system clock to something like Jan 1, 1970, or so. Don't do that. Check the return of system calls to see if they succeed or not.